# failing to connect to Wifi while connecting my ESP32 to AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, esp32

Last night I tried to connect my ESP32 to AWS with some fake data but it was not connecting as it was showing my IP address as 0. I did send some fake data from my ESP to AWS 2 days ago and it worked and uploaded my Data to AWS IoT Core successfuly. I am on 2.4GHz network. But now it is not uploading my Data. What could be this failing to connect to my wifi issue?? Why it is so?? Why suddenly its not uploading when initially it did upload data on AWS Cloud. Do I need to do some adjustments or my ESP32 has gone faulty?

---

```
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h> 

const char* ssid = "Mechatron";
const char* password = "IoTworld";

const char* awsEndpoint = "a8o60o3sv2p1u5-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; 

// xxxxxxxxxx-certificate.pem.crt
const char* certificate_pem_crt = \

"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"FIIDWTCCAkGgAwIBAgIUMAH+oQhNNicbXAXujxiVFPYVYA8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\n" \
"BQAwTTFLMEkGA1UECwxCQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcyBPPUFtYXpvbi5jb20g\n" \
"SW5jLiBMPVNlYXR0bGUgU1Q9V2FzaGluZ3RvbiBDPVVTMB4XDTIyMDUxNzA2MTM0\n" \
"NFoXDTQ5MTIzMTIzNTk1OVowHjEcMBoGA1UEAwwTQVdTIElvVCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0\n" \
"ZTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALTDfScg36QoISlzxf8y\n" \
"ta2Bggc5dB8XnGAZOLQN8OdroUHdcJDp7RQQ2VeOOCzXq/QU4rN4ygag6x0dacky\n" \
"TIn39jFKDA9JKVPYfdxKbIHCjjgQJtvAf4em10eKThgewQhkVD9QFIgqIAxbqvq4\n" \
"6jA9O+LEHpb0bxPJy27OwiSLIM0IOoIzMULT9rifqNmFUd0PTMr7Ce14YibON47i\n" \
"l/WDzwtnrDdPt6zPNRE45E43PAX7pB/qMhyJrSHoDVjwJV/8ktSnlZ9AViLFL4pu\n" \
"sIOALGx+0obyAadqOTMiD5gK4cVd43vZ9Pv31KsZPeIGL3ofYqBU888W1dcOC2qX\n" \
"fCECAwEAAaNgMF4wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUK7f8+C6ZW2vBKKNf6Ivh6VdnbRAwHQYD\n" \
"VR0OBBYEFKGplO5nt63sDAuMKB7opvHsRq/5MAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwDgYDVR0P\n" \
"AQH/BAQDAgeAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQDDFpp/SMvYyL6wqkWnrd8hfb0g\n" \
"QSx7WM+FS5i/PjiRYSj3Ems6epm+wZBFqZyBRXS7imgXqPRpy7l5RPX0atHArF2O\n" \
"6NVVpIsgZcg6nBKkWv9/NrICm0Vg/pFSe+cUPQzE2B3txeiurLFlQbHmkLneQbfy\n" \
"EY1eGqEUmXXNCdefr9EDFeqGt+Iq3OaqybeZDZFbnl8eEOhR3DfOE8d6Nd8Igoql\n" \
"Sh6u917emTu+JJCWJckg7K0BSZguyZUV6NoBvx+GJVeZ5VSmi9mehbhmJHRi7Nv1\n" \
"5x3N3T9QdbM5Yrjl3TvwovVEqgMcspux/HMAMDVnuNaDqTx9JY+ulG7JKMfD\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

// xxxxxxxxxx-private.pem.key
const char* private_pem_key = \

"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" \
"HIIEogIBAAKCAQEAtMN9JyDfpCghKXPF/zK1rYGCBzl0HxecYBk4tA3w52uhQd1w\n" \
"kOntFBDZV444LNer9BTis3jKBqDrHR1pyTJMiff2MUoMD0kpU9h93EpsgcKOOBAm\n" \
"28B/h6bXR4pOGB7BCGRUP1AUiCogDFuq+rjqMD074sQelvRvE8nLbs7CJIsgzQg6\n" \
"gjMxQtP2uJ+o2YVR3Q9MyvsJ7XhiJs43juKX9YPPC2esN0+3rM81ETjkTjc8Bfuk\n" \
"H+oyHImtIegNWPAlX/yS1KeVn0BWIsUvim6wg4AsbH7ShvIBp2o5MyIPmArhxV3j\n" \
"e9n0+/fUqxk94gYveh9ioFTzzxbV1w4Lapd8IQIDAQABAoIBADSroZP9KC0U5FTH\n" \
"vzGU/QsJaXHhc8x7fL0jnDoatc84tUwT0fDnuITYQ/wXHJc0YI5GZ6gT0goMaXWa\n" \
"VHCjj1nEPqAuC0WI89nSgxnlNai5n+cGDcyKUp6cJq5ZxleQ3n4rfcDU/KaQX7Y6\n" \
"H5/esZ5MuV5h9ufVYWhKrFQlOryasALN3qprTD+dvfPYB8nezDmSuTKul6WnBABu\n" \
"rT1HF3IhZiJEjnNI8nZB8W/ACAM2FKzbQaFrdDQ7Y96L9KXAsvVLYFsHJBre59da\n" \
"bebIuHwZTG+/2AINKApIMtBnlLCmhPM+/QQR7k+E/y9JrWK4qDudoBlDR9PCMJPI\n" \
"6tkfvIECgYEA4F0x5nhGh+qsGiUwhBq+LD3czCYjMBfhJQoThyGiNWnvSbgJk+AN\n" \
"d0UBQjR25fkpYpYjevM/2GKZ0q3RQsl5wtGeaissksvnI5Yd61hCHL8VVYN1FXZQ\n" \
"lq+PX+kEFtDrvn3OX8xZD6mYHwgThTEvVKBQorut1Gsxat40m1c2FvUCgYEAzkB2\n" \
"Um0aJv/dP/khxPKY8uOHMOLxPMRXgvAUDsBq5h8kOqHWM+fWLRyQm27PMCit3UIo\n" \
"Zv5foXqqke2aV1qEiDoX8XNvObWZuWILr9s2/XLioLx5EJXevET2c0n6TBspJN1V\n" \
"Kw7cWJfu5wU/5OzRIZOyR3gSrWYfDxaJcw0gHP0CgYB9hKW+Aduzfh36IoQZ47ww\n" \
"lAtKSqu05CcYyaJTHwXYTAOKgmMZT2c5Kmmh2CgMUHBOrx/6UMuPCtpzerpvWre7\n" \
"vfmZ+71cAqa0ye7DEwUpf903keuWrjI3ms/gIEEhYpAAafFitre8g2yPL7177iBE\n" \
"f8ucvtJo2+8xkk5r+UZRYQKBgCr6E62pPkHSHvAtoXPAeU5jStBM+aeH4hROol9K\n" \
"iPXal1oATvoR3PcZdKhuto16bIAmQPT1HEgxn0k5EWgSXHtmX4bYXtzPknCmlXjX\n" \
"XOYDAmYr364tDHR+ijwLtjQVlMUxuYV3W0K6pfVNirrQ/eLZO9TYmEu5c89ZCtsG\n" \
"aSKhAoGAUqv1Hfc3d100lLQV8yABqcJ7MPDYjb23su7i3WTNET8hA8yjM6WeQfMq\n" \
"ZbuDy7CndfdvYUcb/Dr8YapeSfYIKYC5ydGzILVan3XVcAFKbiQ1ea67OP0ZBevA\n" \
"0zVObTehKJiyunTpRxCigtTRR+YVAgYeM5Ej9XxhlwYkwxX+g3o=\n" \
"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

/* root CA can be downloaded in:
  https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/VeriSign-Class%203-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem
*/
const char* rootCA = \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIIDQTCCAimgAwIBAgITBmyfz5m/jAo54vB4ikPmljZbyjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF\n" \
"ADA5MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEPMA0GA1UEChMGQW1hem9uMRkwFwYDVQQDExBBbWF6\n" \
"b24gUm9vdCBDQSAxMB4XDTE1MDUyNjAwMDAwMFoXDTM4MDExNzAwMDAwMFowOTEL\n" \
"MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDzANBgNVBAoTBkFtYXpvbjEZMBcGA1UEAxMQQW1hem9uIFJv\n" \
"b3QgQ0EgMTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALJ4gHHKeNXj\n" \
"ca9HgFB0fW7Y14h29Jlo91ghYPl0hAEvrAIthtOgQ3pOsqTQNroBvo3bSMgHFzZM\n" \
"9O6II8c+6zf1tRn4SWiw3te5djgdYZ6k/oI2peVKVuRF4fn9tBb6dNqcmzU5L/qw\n" \
"IFAGbHrQgLKm+a/sRxmPUDgH3KKHOVj4utWp+UhnMJbulHheb4mjUcAwhmahRWa6\n" \
"VOujw5H5SNz/0egwLX0tdHA114gk957EWW67c4cX8jJGKLhD+rcdqsq08p8kDi1L\n" \
"93FcXmn/6pUCyziKrlA4b9v7LWIbxcceVOF34GfID5yHI9Y/QCB/IIDEgEw+OyQm\n" \
"jgSubJrIqg0CAwEAAaNCMEAwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMC\n" \
"AYYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFIQYzIU07LwMlJQuCFmcx7IQTgoIMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA\n" \
"A4IBAQCY8jdaQZChGsV2USggNiMOruYou6r4lK5IpDB/G/wkjUu0yKGX9rbxenDI\n" \
"U5PMCCjjmCXPI6T53iHTfIUJrU6adTrCC2qJeHZERxhlbI1Bjjt/msv0tadQ1wUs\n" \
"N+gDS63pYaACbvXy8MWy7Vu33PqUXHeeE6V/Uq2V8viTO96LXFvKWlJbYK8U90vv\n" \
"o/ufQJVtMVT8QtPHRh8jrdkPSHCa2XV4cdFyQzR1bldZwgJcJmApzyMZFo6IQ6XU\n" \
"5MsI+yMRQ+gDKXJioaldXgjUkK642M4UwtBV8ob2xJNDd2ZhwLnoQdeXeGADbkpy\n" \
"rqXRfboQnoZsG4q5WTP468SQvvf5\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

WiFiClientSecure wiFiClient;
void msgReceived(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int len);
PubSubClient pubSubClient(awsEndpoint, 8883, msgReceived, wiFiClient); 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200); delay(50); Serial.println();
  Serial.println("ESP32 AWS IoT Example");
  Serial.printf("SDK version: %s\n", ESP.getSdkVersion());

  Serial.print("Connecting to "); Serial.print(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  WiFi.waitForConnectResult();
  Serial.print(", WiFi connected, IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  wiFiClient.setCACert(rootCA);
  wiFiClient.setCertificate(certificate_pem_crt);
  wiFiClient.setPrivateKey(private_pem_key);
}

unsigned long lastPublish;
int msgCount;

void loop()
{
  pubSubCheckConnect();
  
  if (millis() - lastPublish > 10000)
  {
    String msg = String("Hello from ESP32: ") + ++msgCount;
    boolean rc = pubSubClient.publish("outTopic", msg.c_str()); 
    Serial.print("Published, rc="); Serial.print( (rc ? "OK: " : "FAILED: ") );
    Serial.println(msg);
    lastPublish = millis();
  }
}

void msgReceived(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length)
{
  Serial.print("Message received on "); Serial.print(topic); Serial.print(": ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void pubSubCheckConnect()
{
  if ( ! pubSubClient.connected())
  {
    Serial.print("PubSubClient connecting to: "); Serial.print(awsEndpoint);
    while ( ! pubSubClient.connected())
    {
      Serial.print(".");
      pubSubClient.connect("ESPthingXXXX");
      delay(1000);
    }
    Serial.println(" connected");
    pubSubClient.subscribe("inTopic");
  }
  pubSubClient.loop();
}
```

Comment: Hi AbiBakar, welcome to SO. Please post your code as [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help you without your code. Also describe what is the WiFi setup you're using.

Comment: try the basic examples like the WifiScan

Comment: ESP32 AWS IoT Example
SDK version: v3.3.5-1-g85c43024c
Connecting to Mechatron, WiFi connected, IP address: 0.0.0.0
PubSubClient connecting to: a8o60o3sv2p1u5-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com............. (I am getting this output in my serial monitor)

Answer (score 0):

Connection to WiFi failed, but your code proceeds blindly without checking for failures. You need to look at the return code of `waitForConnectResult()` to see if the connection to WiFi succeeded or not. Seems like you're on some older version of Arduino core for ESP32, so maybe [this document](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/station-class.html#waitforconnectresult) will help

```
if (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() == WL_CONNECTED) {
  Serial.print(", WiFi connected, IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
} else {
  Serial.println(", failed to connect to WiFi");
}
```

Comment: Yes Tarmo, you are right. My Wifi is failing to connect. Even I tried to connect my ESP32 to thingspeak still my wifi is not connecting. what to do now?

Comment: There are a few common reasons. ESP32 doesn't support 5 GHz WiFi so make sure your access point is on 2.4 GHz. Obviously the password may be wrong, the access point may have a whitelist etc.

Comment: Yes, Tarmo I am on 2.4GHz Network. I didi post some fake data to AWS successfully from the similar network. But now I am not being able to send it with the same code havng failed to connect to Wifi error. Do I need to make some adjustments or my ESP32 has gone faulty?

Comment: No. There's a problem with your WiFi setup.